# What's wrong in this code. Why does it still display the MsgBox if the user selects or does not select the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

**It still gives a MsgBox whether I select the checkbox box or not...**

My code below will redirect to Google in both conditions: If the user selects the checkbox, then it will redirect to www.google.com, but if a user forgets to check the checkbox then it shows the message box with an *OK* button. When I click on OK it should redirect to www.google.com

**I want**

When a user forgets to check any of the checkboxes to show a MsgBox with an *OK* button and stay on the same page. Otherwise if user selects any of the checkboxes then redirect to www.google.com.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head runat="server">
         <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
        </div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick ="return ConfirmSelection(this.form);" Text="Button" />

        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ConfirmSelection(frm)
            {
                for (i=0; i<=1; i++) {
                    //chkSubjectOfInterest is the id of your checkbox control

                    if (frm.elements[i].name.indexOf('chkSubjectOfInterest') != -1)
                    {
                        if (frm.elements[i].checked)
                        {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                }
                alert('You haven\'t selected an item yet!')
                return false
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the error you get or the behaviour you'd like?

Comment: [For loop syntax][1]


  [1]: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: You should not edit your question to remove everything of value or it will get closed as not a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bit?

```
 for (i=0; i   {
```

It should be something like:

```
for (i=0; i <= loopnumber; i++)
{

}
```

Comment: That's odd. Usually it'd be `i < loopnumber`, and in this case, most likely to be `i < frm.elements.length`.

Answer (score 2):

`for (i=0; i   {`

is incomplete?

`for (i=0; i<something.length;i++)   {`

Comment: `something` => `frm.elements.length`