# What's the problem with this code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

**Where to modify this code**

**IT STILL GIVES A MSGBOX IF I SELECT THE CHECKBOX BOX OR NOT ....**

My code below will redirect to Google in both conditions: If the user selects the checkbox, then it will redirect to www.google.com, but if a user forgets to check the checkbox then it shows the msg box with an ok button. When I click on ok it should redirect to www.google.com

**I want**

When a user forgets to check any of the checkboxes to show a msgbox with an ok button and stay on the same page.  Otherwise if user selects any of the checkboxes then redirect to www.google.com

**What's wrong with this code?**

```
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />

    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick ="ConfirmSelection(this.form)" Text="Button" />


    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function ConfirmSelection(frm) 
{ 
   for (i=0; i<=1; i++) {
     //chkSubjectOfInterest is the id of your checkbox control

     if (frm.elements[i].name.indexOf('chkSubjectOfInterest') !=-1) 
     { 
       if (frm.elements[i].checked) 
       { 
         return true
       } 
     } 
   } 
   alert('You havent selected an Item yet!')
   return false
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One error is that the javascript code lacks `;` at the end of the statements...

Comment: You haven't included any of your server-side code for controlling the redirect?

Comment: Duplicate, update your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817220/whats-the-error-in-this-code

Comment: @eckes: Unnecessary if you put statements each in a new line. More statements in single line must be separated with `;` each!

Comment: @Cipi: whow. Didn't know that. Anyway, relying on automatic semicolon insertion seems a bit dangerous to me (and at least also to the two upvoters of my comment `:-)`)

Comment: @eckes, @Cipi a worse problem is the missing `var` for "i" in the `for` loop

Comment: @user583181 you shouldn't remove your question details. No one will ever know what this question was about.

Comment: Please don't wipe the question after it has been answered. Keep it here in case it helps others. I've rolled it back to a previous version.

Comment: How to close the question f i wanna open new one ?

Comment: You don't need to close to open a new one. Just go ahead and ask a new question. And please choose a title that better reflects the content of your question.

Comment: Then why you people always says a duplicate question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a return in your function call. Also ensure your function ConfirmSelection has explicit return value in both parts of the if statements

```
OnClientClick ="return ConfirmSelection(this.form);"
```

Comment: it still give a msgboc if i select or not sect the checkboxes