# What's wrong in this code? Why does it still give a MsgBox if the user selects or does not select the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

**Where to modify this code**

**It still gives a msgbox whether I select the checkbox box or not ....**

My code below will redirect to Google in both conditions: If the user selects the checkbox, then it will redirect to www.google.com, but if a user forgets to check the checkbox then it shows the message box with an *OK* button. When I click *OK* it should redirect to www.google.com.

**I want**

When a user forgets to check any of the checkboxes it should show a message box with an OK button and stay on the same page. Otherwise if the user selects any of the checkboxes then redirect to www.google.com.

**What's wrong with this code?**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick ="ConfirmSelection(this.form)" Text="Button" />
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ConfirmSelection(frm)
            {
                for (i=0; i<=1; i++) {
                    //chkSubjectOfInterest is the id of your checkbox control

                    if (frm.elements[i].name.indexOf('chkSubjectOfInterest') !=-1)
                    {
                        if (frm.elements[i].checked)
                        {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                }
                alert('You haven\'t selected an item yet!')
                return false
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [thank you all  for helping me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817220/thank-you-all-for-helping-me)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817704/thankyou-all-my-friends-to-helping-me-in-this-code

Comment: Exact duplicate of *[What's wrong in this code. Why does it still display the MsgBox if the user selects or does not select the checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817220)* (reposted). That question was closed as ***"not a real question"***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this JavaScript function:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function checkboxChecked(){
    var checked=false;
    var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0; i<allInputs.length; i++){
         var chk=allInputs[i];
         if(chk.type == "checkbox"){
            if(chk.checked){
               checked=true;
               break;
            }
         } 
    }
    if(!checked)
        alert("You should check something!!");
    return checked;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" /><input type="checkbox" /><input type="checkbox" /><input type="checkbox" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick ="javascript:return checkboxChecked();" Text="Button" />
</body>
</html>
```

This works also with ASP.NET checkboxes.

Comment: Ya...but it redirect to the page and follow post back on each conditions ...

i want if user doesn't select any checkbox then it stay on same page otherwise redirect to other page

Comment: Where is the problem? If you want to prevent the submit-button click that does a Postback, you only have to return false from the button-click-handler. If user selected something the postback will occur and you can redirect from codebehind via `Response.Redirect(URL)` . Moment, i will edit my answer.

Comment: but....in this code if user doesn't select the checkbox then msgbox appear as alert("You should check something!!"); with okey button ...when user click on okey then postback triggers ... and if i use on buttonclick ... me.response.redirect "~Default.aspx" it still redirect to default.aspx if he select the check box or not

Comment: I want if user doesn't select the checkbox then the msg box appear with okey button when i click n okey button then user stay on that page without post back ... and if user select check box then it redirect to default2.aspx ....in this your code if user doesn't select checbox them msgbox will popup with okey button ... and after user clcik on okey button it redirect to other page ..and if user select checkbox then user redirect to same page without msg box

Comment: You should have noticed that i've  not only edited the js-function to return a boolean but also changed the event-handler of your button: `OnClientClick ="javascript:return checkboxChecked();"` Because i return false if user selects nothing, the page will not postback.

Comment: Ya thanks tim .... can you plz provide me the persomal email ..or Gtalk ..you are really great ..

Comment: Is this applicable on usercontrol ..if i use this on usercontrols. ..if all the controls of mine in usercontrols of asp.net ?

Comment: Depends on how many usercontrols you have on your page. It will validate all checkboxes on the page per default.  If you really need more UserControls with this checkbox-collection on your page, i have to modify my example a bit. Then you should embed your checkbox in a container like a div/asp.net-panel with an ID. Then you can get this element as js-control and use `getElementsByTagName` on this container-control to find all checkboxes in it.

Comment: tim .... one more thing ...i want .... how to modify this code ...if i have already checked and disabled checkboxes then this code will fail to works ...

Comment: In this already checked and disabled checkbox will be counted as checked and the msg box will not pop up even after i haven't select checkbox recently ..

Comment: Then you should change this line `if(chk.checked){` to this `if(chk.checked && !chk.disabled){`